# Order List<String> of Data with Chapters vs. Units

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have a `List<String>` of Units and Chapters for a basic flashcard game. I would like to order them least to greatest (E.G. Chapter 1, Unit 1, Chapter 2 etc...)

Using this code:

```
String UnitsChaptersString = Utils.GetReviewUnitsChapters().replaceAll(" ", "_");

List<String> UnitsChaptersList = Arrays.asList(UnitsChaptersString.split(","));

for (int i = 0; i < UnitsChaptersList.size(); i++) {

    // Order and add to the RecyclerView here...

}
```

I obtain and loop through a list of units and chapters.

An example `String` value returned by `Utils.GetReviewUnitsChapters()...` is this:

`Chapter_3,Unit_2,Chapter_1`

With the string above, the end result should be: `Chapter_1,Chapter_3,Unit_2.`

For clarity, `Unit_2` is greater than both `Chapter_1` and `Chapter_3`, but `Unit_1` is only greater than `Chapter_1`.

**Important Note:** Units 'hold' chapters! Chapters are a subsidiary of Units.

Visual Tree:

**Unit_1:**

- Chapter 1
- Chapter 2
- Etc...

**Unit_2:**

- Chapter 5
- Chapter 6
- And so on.

I had this same question for Swift ([Eliminate array .sorted errors Swift 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73954632/eliminate-array-sorted-errors-swift-5)). Note that in Swift, there is a nice `.sorted()` function available. Might there be one for Java?

StackOverflow tried to send me to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42428419/ordering-of-data-with-firebase-android), but it wasn't the answer to my question.

I also looked into the `List.sort(...)` option, but I ran into the wall of `Comparators` and `super Strings`, so I was unable to implement that on my own.

### **Update:**

Using one of the suggested methods, I used this code:

```
List<String> TestList = Arrays.asList("Chapter_1", "Unit_3", "Chapter_42", "Chapter_2");

        Collections.sort(TestList);

        for (int i = 0; i < TestList.size(); i++) {

            Log.i("SortedList", TestList.get(i));

        }
```

And got this:

```
I/SortedList: Chapter_1
I/SortedList: Chapter_2
I/SortedList: Chapter_42
I/SortedList: Unit_3
```

`Unit_3` should be after `Chapter_2` but before `Chapter_42`.

In other words, the output needs to be:

```
I/SortedList: Chapter_1
I/SortedList: Chapter_2
I/SortedList: Unit_3
I/SortedList: Chapter_42
```

Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like a chapter is made up of units, where units are not unique _across chapters_. I would suggest that a flat list is not the correct way to model this data. Nor, necessarily, is relying directly on `String`. Perhaps you should create custom classes with this (e.g., a `Chapter` class that has-a list of `Unit`s).

Comment: @Slaw, no, my "Chapters" aren't made up of units. And, since my data isn't really in need of a model, I don't want to go down that route.

Comment: If you want to stay with a list this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708698/how-can-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically) could be quite helpful. Otherwise I would go with Slaw's approach.

Comment: @vincere Well, based off your edit, I mostly just got it the wrong way around. A unit is made up of chapters. And given your tree-like structure, I still think modeling your data with classes is the right approach. Later, if you really want a flat list, you can add that functionality (take the tree and flatten it; if the chapters are in order, and the units of each chapter are in order, then the flattened list will be in order). Regardless, you need to somehow record the fact that a chapter belongs to a unit, or maybe give everything sequential IDs (in the right order).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to solve this is probably not to keep this data as strings, but as an actual data structure.

If you're stuck with strings, use sort with a custom comparator that decides which comes first based on your criteria (which would require splitting that string into a number and a type, then comparing first the number then the type).

Comment: Thanks! This was my final option, and I guess I'll get to work.